# In C, assignment of function pointer to appropriately-typed variable gives "cannot convert ... in assignment"

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Take the following C/C++ code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int inc(int i) { return i+1; }  // int→int, like abs()
// baz is bool→(int→int)
int (*baz(bool b))(int) { return b ? &abs : &inc; }

int main() {
  int (*foo(bool))(int);  // foo is &(bool→(int→int))
  foo = baz;
}
```

Attempting to compile this (gcc or g++) gives:

```
$ g++ test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:9: error: assignment of function ‘int (* foo(bool))(int)’
test.cc:9: error: cannot convert ‘int (*(bool))(int)’ to ‘int (*(bool))(int)’ in assignment
```

Check for yourself: the two types it claims it cannot convert between are *exactly the same*.  Why then is it claiming that they are incompatible?

**EDIT 1**: The problem disappears when using `typedef`s (as is recommended), like so:

```
int main() {
  typedef int (*int2int)(int);
  typedef int2int (*bool2_int2int)(bool);
  bool2_int2int foo;
  foo = baz;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: The compiler, of course, was right.  The problem with my original code, as many pointed out, is that `foo` in `main()` is a declaration of a function, and not a function pointer.  The error in the assignment was therefore not *conflicting types* but *assigning to a function*, which is not possible.  The correct code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int inc(int i) { return i+1; }  // int→int, like abs()
// baz is bool→(int→int)
int (*baz(bool b))(int) { return b ? &abs : &inc; }

int main() {
  int (*(*foo)(bool))(int);  // foo is &(bool→(int→int))
  foo = &baz;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a bit spaghettilike. What about `int (*(*foo)(bool))(int); foo = &baz;`? And why no typedef? Declare a typedef and create pointers to such functions. `typedef int intfunc(int);` and `typedef intfunc *bazlike(bool);` could help make things clearer.

Comment: It's the error message that's wrong. Which version of g++ are you using? With mine (4.4) I get: "error: assignment of function 'int (* foo(bool))(int)'" and "error: cannot convert 'int (* (*)(bool))(int)' to 'int (*(bool))(int) in assignment" which I think is correct. In you main() function you were declaring a function, not a local variable.

Comment: Achille, I'm also using 4.4, but I think you're referring to another error in my code: the assignment "foo = baz", which is does work as a short form once my primary error was resolved.  Did you correct it to "foo = &baz"?

Comment: With `foo` changed to a function pointer type `foo = baz;` is perfectly legal. The name of a function in an expression is converted to a pointer-to-function type (except where it is the argument to unary `&` or `sizeof`).

Comment: eegg: Well, indeed. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is in fact wrong.  The problem is that this line:

```
int (*foo(bool))(int);  // foo is &(bool→(int→int))
```

... doesn't mean what you think it means.  It's interpreted as a declaration of a function named "foo".  That makes perfect sense.  Think about it - if you had wanted to forward declare "baz", you would have put `int (*baz(bool))(int);` , right?  Also, since baz is a function which returns a function pointer, and foo is a pointer to a function which returns a function pointer, wouldn't you expect the syntax to be more complicated?

You declared foo as a function of the same type as baz, rather than as a *pointer to* a function of same type as baz.

From your compiler, the *first* error message is the useful one - it tells you `assignment of function`, i.e. you have tried to assign to a function, which is an error.

I'm not even going to try to write the correct solution without typedefs :-)  Here's some code which compiles and I think is right, using typedefs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef int(*IntReturnsInt)(int);

int inc(int i) { return i+1; } 
IntReturnsInt baz(bool b) { return b ? &abs : &inc; }

int main() {
  IntReturnsInt (*foo)(bool b);
  foo = baz;
}
```

In this example the double-function-pointer concept is a bit clearer - `IntReturnsInt` is a function pointer type and `foo` is a pointer to a function which returns `IntReturnsInt`... phew :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a function declaration.

```
int (*foo(bool))(int);
```

If you wanted to declare a function pointer, you should do:

```
int (*(*foo)(bool))(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int inc(int i) { return i+1; }  // int→int, like abs()
// baz is bool→(int→int)
int (*baz(bool b))(int) { return b ? &abs : &inc; }

int main() {
  int (*(*foo)(bool))(int);  // foo is &(bool→(int→int))
  foo = baz;
  return 0;
}
```

So there were a few side-issues clouding the core issue. Your "bool" was being interpreted as a default-`int` untyped parameter because the actual built-in is _Bool, humanized by the previously-missing `#include <stdbool.h>`. The lack of a pointer declaration for the object on the stack was confounding its ability to conform to the type of the real function object in static memory just above.

Once I included `<stdbool.h>`, the error shifted to *"lvalue required"* complaint, because there was only a function declaration and not a pointer object. The code above will compile with no warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure, but I think this is closer to the OP's intent:

```
// baz is a function returning a pointer to a function
int (*baz(bool b))(int) { return b ? &abs : &inc; }

int main() {
  // foo is a pointer to a function
  int (*foo)(int) ;
  foo = baz(true); // Now foo is equal to &abs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign to function type (`int (*foo(bool))(int);`), you need to use pointer to function

```
int (*(*foo)(bool))(int);
foo = &baz;
```